# Control the playback speed of Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I'm using MediaPlayer to play back some videos in an Android application, and they are noticeably faster on my device as when viewed on a computer.

Is there any way to control the playback speed of these videos in order to slow them down?

Comment: There is no method of setting the playback speed.

See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614365/control-the-playback-speed-of-video-in-android

Answer (score 8):

Beginning API 23, MediaPlayer can set playback speed using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams%28android.media.PlaybackParams%29).

> Class MediaPlayer
>
> `public void setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params)` Added in API
>   level 23
>
> Sets playback rate using PlaybackParams. Parameters params
>     PlaybackParams: the playback params. Throws IllegalStateException   if
>   the internal player engine has not been initialized.
>   IllegalArgumentException  if params is not supported.

Sample code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = ...; //Whatever
float speed = 0.75f;     
mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
```

For API < 23, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849961/speed-control-of-mediaplayer-in-android).