# Control the playback speed of video in android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am using a VideoView to play a video file kept in res/raw. I couldnt find a way to control the playback speed of the video. Basically i want to reduce and increase the playback while moving a scroll bar. Is there any work around for implementing this?

Comment: hi, i want to implement like you in video view functionality, i did't get any idea, if you have find any solution for this please send me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change the playback rate by simply using `VideoView`. `VideoView` and `MediaPlayer` only provide limited media functions.

You have to use some third party library, e.g., PVPlayer, and implement that yourself.

That's also why good media players on Android are so valuable:)

Answer (score 16):

you can use this but it works on api 23 and above

```
 mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            //works only from api 23
            PlaybackParams myPlayBackParams = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                myPlayBackParams = new PlaybackParams();
                myPlayBackParams.setSpeed(0.8f); //you can set speed here
                mp.setPlaybackParams(myPlayBackParams);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: brief coding, excelent

Comment: can guarantee this works than using `mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));`

Answer (score 2):

I want to say than [Mk Kamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10211376/mk-kamal)'s solution have an unexpected side effect: calling `setPlaybackParams` in `OnPreparedListener` will force `VideoView` to repeat the latest played video when the app was returned from the background.
I don't know is it a bug or a feature, but I found a way to avoid such behavior:

```
private float speed = 0.8f;
private final MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener listener = (mp, what, extra) -> {

    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START) {
        mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};


videoView.setOnPreparedListener(
                mp -> {
                    mp.setOnInfoListener(listener);
                }
        );
```

`MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START` will be sent only if the palyer was already started.

And I want to emphasize that `getPlaybackParams` is annotated as `@NonNull`, so it's not necessary to create a new `PlaybackParams` object.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin variant, API above 23

```
val playerView = itemView.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoview)
playerView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + R.raw.123.mp4))

playerView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
   playerView.seekTo(1) // for video preview
   mediaPlayer.playbackParams = mediaPlayer.playbackParams.apply {
      speed = 0.6f
   }
   playerView.start()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

DicePlayer works perfectly on my Asus Transformer.
It has a speed control onscreen display.

I'm not sure what `res/raw` is though.

Comment: Question was about implementing speed control in android, not about existing apps. Therefor deserved negative points