# Android and MediaPlayer : How to change playback rate?

Tags: android, video

I try to add a video on my Android Application with the VideoView but it's not possible to change the Playback rate with VideoView : [Control the playback speed of video in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614365/control-the-playback-speed-of-video-in-android)

So I try to add a video with MediaPlayer like that :

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4

        try {

            String url = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"; // your URL here

            // メディアプレイヤーの作成
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();

            SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(this);
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surface.getHolder());
            setContentView(surface);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("例外が発生しました。");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

When I build my application on my Phone, the video can play (I can here the sound) but there are not pictures (the screen is white).

Where is my error ?

And next question : How to change playback rate ?
Is this code ok ?

```
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surface.getHolder());
            setContentView(surface);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                PlaybackParams myPlayBackParams = new PlaybackParams();
                myPlayBackParams.setSpeed(2.0f);
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(myPlayBackParams);
            }
```

Sorry, I can't check this code by my self because there are not pictures (there is only sound and it's look like no effect).

Thank you !

Comment: If I try it  in onCreate I got notting as result, because Surface is not created. (Where is this information in the Android documentation? ==> I hate Android so much !!!). So now, I have a new question: How can I create the Surface?